# how to custom ubuntu live CD with gcc installed

Tags: gcc, iso, live-cd

I want to make an Ubuntu image with gcc so that I can run gcc directly after the system is installed. The version of Ubuntu is Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS. How can I package the gcc related installation package into the iso file of Ubuntu, and then it can be installed offline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: I'm sorry that the link doesn't help me. The answer is about desktop ubuntu but my condition is about server ubuntu

Comment: The 2nd answer is another approach of customizing your OS installation by editing the `squashfs` file, thus enables you to edit the contents of the installed OS regardless the type (Desktop / Server), and should also work. This is how I customize my OS installations.